# My simple Javascript RegExp to parse food orders is laughing at me

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm stuck with this simple regex that I'm writing to parse food orders.
I get every order as a JSON object, something like this:

```
{"text": "order"}
```

> Rules

People order food in an almost uniform fashion, but not quite. So I've decided to set some rules of what I consider a food order in order to be able to parse it.

- baseline format: `{"text": "restaurant name: food order"}` `[1-10,16,17]`
- `restaurant name` is **always** at the start of `text` `[1-10]`
- there are **no spaces** preceding `restaurant name` `[1-10]`
- sometimes `restaurant name` will be **bolded** `[2,5,7,8]`
- sometimes, even the `:` will be **bolded** `[3,6,10]`
- sometimes, **unicode characters** are present in the restaurant name `[8]`
- sometimes, **unicode characters** are present in the food order `[1-10]`
- sometimes, a food order spans **several lines** `[3-6,8-10]`
- sometimes, there are **several orders** in `text` `[8-10]`

> Valid food orders

These are valid food orders that the regex should be able to parse:

```
 [1] {"text": "Xanacuk:   Ensalada de Espinacas + Crema del d\u00eda. :grin: "}
 [2] {"text": "*Xanacuk*:  Ensalada de Espinacas + Crema del d\u00eda"}
 [3] {"text": "*Xanacuk:*\nEnsalada de Espinacas + Crema del d\u00eda. Thanks! :sunglasses:  "} 
 [4] {"text": "pok\u00e9 restaurant:\n1- Crea tu Bowl: At\u00fan, Smoked Paprika,  Cebolla Roja\n1- Salm\u00f3n Wasabi Pomelo"}
 [5] {"text": "*POKE restaurant*:\n1- Crea tu Bowl: At\u00fan, Smoked Paprika,  Cebolla Roja\n1- Salm\u00f3n Wasabi Pomelo"}
 [6] {"text": "*POKE restaurant:*\n1- Crea tu Bowl: At\u00fan, Smoked Paprika,  Cebolla Roja\n1- Salm\u00f3n Wasabi Pomelo"}
 [7] {"text": "*Xanacuk Place*: Ensalada de dise\u00f1o peque\u00f1a (base espinacas + jam\u00f3n cocido + at\u00fan + aceite extra virgen)  + mollete malasa\u00f1a. Gracias!"}
 [8] {"text": "*Ohana Pok\u00e9 House*: Bowl - Arroz Negro Salvaje, At\u00fan, Tuna flakes, Zanahoria, Edamame , Wakame, Nori Furikake\n*Tierra Burrito*: Cookie Doble Chocolate"}
 [9] {"text": "Poke Bowl: Bowl , \nBaby Spinach , \nAt\u00fan, \nSiracha de Manzana, Tuna Flakes, Pepino, Edamame , Cacahuete, Granada\n*Tierra Burrito*: Cookie Doble Chocolate"}
[10] {"text": "*Poke:* Bowl , \nBaby Spinach , \nAt\u00fan, \nSiracha de Manzana, Tuna Flakes, Pepino, Edamame , Cacahuete, Granada\n*Tierra Burrito*: Cookie Doble Chocolate "}
```

> Invalid food orders

These don't comply with the rules, so regex should return `null`:

```
[11] {"text: ":heart: everywhere"}
[12] {"text: "this is not a food order"}
[13] {"text: "Mike +1"}
[14] {"text: "It\u2019s hot in here :fire:"}
[15] {"text: "we need to talk"}
```

> False positives

Naturally, some false positives are inevitable, this is OK:

```
[16] {"text: "Hey: :heart:"}
[17] {"text: "Jim: come here"}
```

> Parsed food orders

So the expected results are:

```
 [1] restaurant: "Xanacuk"
     order: "Ensalada de Espinacas + Crema del día"
 [2] restaurant: "Xanacuk"
     order: "Ensalada de Espinacas + Crema del día"
 [3] restaurant: "Xanacuk"
     order: "Ensalada de Espinacas + Crema del día. Thanks! :sunglasses:"
 [4] restaurant: "poké restaurant"
     order: "1- Crea tu Bowl: Atún, Smoked Paprika,  Cebolla Roja
             1- Salmón Wasabi Pomelo"
 [5] restaurant: "POKE restaurant"
     order: "1- Crea tu Bowl: Atún, Smoked Paprika,  Cebolla Roja
             1- Salmón Wasabi Pomelo"
 [6] restaurant: "POKE restaurant"
     order: "1- Crea tu Bowl: Atún, Smoked Paprika,  Cebolla Roja
             1- Salmón Wasabi Pomelo"
 [7] restaurant: "Xanacuk Place"
     order: "Ensalada de diseño pequeña (base espinacas + jamón cocido + atún + aceite extra virgen)  + mollete malasaña. Gracias!"
 [8] restaurant: "Ohana Poké House"
     order: "Bowl - Arroz Negro Salvaje, Atún, Tuna flakes, Zanahoria, Edamame , Wakame, Nori Furikake"
     restaurant: "Tierra Burrito"
     order: "Cookie Doble Chocolate"
 [9] restaurant: "Poke Bowl"
     order: "Bowl , 
             Baby Spinach , 
             Atún, 
             Siracha de Manzana, Tuna Flakes, Pepino, Edamame , Cacahuete, Granada"
     restaurant: "Tierra Burrito"
     order: "Cookie Doble Chocolate"
[10] restaurant: "Poke"
     order: "Bowl , 
             Baby Spinach , 
             Atún, 
             Siracha de Manzana, Tuna Flakes, Pepino, Edamame , Cacahuete, Granada"
     restaurant: "Tierra Burrito"
     order: "Cookie Doble Chocolate"
[11] null
[12] null
[13] null
[14] null
[15] null
[16] restaurant: "Hey"
     order: ":heart:" 
[17] restaurant: "Jim"
     order: "come here"
```

Note: `restaurant` and `order` are always trimmed and any newline at the beginning and the end should be removed as well

> My solution

After doing `JSON.parse(event)` I apply my regex to `event.text`.

So far, I've been able to come up with this regex:

`/\*?([\w ]+)\*?:\*?(?:\s*)((\n|.)+)/gm`

Regex **will work** with `[1-3,5-7,11-17]`

Regex **will not work** with:

- `[4]`: unicode in `restaurant name`
- `[8-10]`: two orders in `text`

Regex creates a third capture group which is not aesthetically pleasant, but I simply ignore it... :-)

regex snippets: https://regex101.com/r/AbtLgm/13

I feel I'm very close. I just need a little push...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: First parse the content as JSON and then you just have to worry about the value of the "text" property.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I do: JSON.parse() and then play with regex on `text`, but my regex won't split properly... :-)

Comment: Could you give us a snippet to work with?

Comment: Sebastian, you're totally right. I forgot to paste the snippet! My bad! https://regex101.com/r/AbtLgm/13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect, but this is what I ended up doing:

`/^\*?([\w \u00a0-\u0200]+)\*? *:\*? *(.+)/gm`

https://regex101.com/r/ymvYb1/4

I might give it another go, but for now... it works! :-)